# SQL Server: find duplicate and for each of them print both rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, duplicates, common-table-expression

There are endless examples on Stack Overflow about how to find duplicate rows in SQL Server. But my goal is to:

1. Find duplicates
2. Print both of them, not only one of them

For example, I'm using this query to find in my database all commerce which have the same `Street_Number`, `Street` and `City`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Street, Street_Number, City ORDER BY Street, Street_Number, City DESC) AS Counting,
        *   
    FROM 
        GoogleDetails 
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE 
WHERE Counting > 1
ORDER BY Street_Number
```

But this query returns just one row - I want to see both of them.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, you can try to replace row_number by count like this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        Count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Street, Street_Number, City) AS Counting,
        *   
    FROM 
        GoogleDetails 
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE 
WHERE Counting > 1
ORDER BY Street_Number
```

Comment: I will take this one for the simplicity. You are a teacher. I learned so many thinks thanks to this post

Answer (score 2):

You can try to write a subquery to get the `COUNT` group by `Street`,`Street_Number`,`City`, which the amount greater than `1`, then self-join get your expect row.

```
SELECT     t2.* 
FROM       ( 
                    SELECT   street, 
                             street_number, 
                             city 
                    FROM     googledetails 
                    GROUP BY street, 
                             street_number, 
                             city 
                    HAVING   Count(*) > 1 ) t1 
INNER JOIN googledetails t2 
ON         t1.street = t2.street 
AND        t1.street_number = t2.street_number
AND        t1.city = t2.city
```

or you can try to use `EXISTS` make it.

```
SELECT t2.* 
FROM   googledetails t2 
WHERE  EXISTS 
       ( 
                SELECT   1 
                FROM     googledetails t1 
                WHERE    t1.street = t2.street 
                AND      t1.street_number = t2.street_number
                AND      t1.city = t2.city 
                GROUP BY t1.street, 
                         t1.street_number, 
                         t1.city 
                HAVING   count(*) > 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Other method, with exists but with an different ID, Better performance than using a group by:

```
SELECT f0.* 
FROM   googledetails f0 
WHERE  EXISTS 
(
    select * from googledetails f1 
    where f1.ID<>f0.ID and f1.street = f0.street
    and f1.street_number = f0.street_number and f1.city = f0.city
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Other method, with cross apply

```
SELECT f0.* 
FROM   googledetails f0 
cross apply
(
    select count(*) Counter 
    from googledetails f1 
    where f1.street = f0.street and f1.street_number = f0.street_number and f1.city = f0.city

) f2
where f2.Counter>1
```